# Can you access a parent field from a child object in Django?

Tags: python, sql, django, api-design

**tl;dr:** I want to express something like `[child.child_field_value, child.parent_field_value]` on a Django child model and get an iterable like `['Alsatian', 'Dog']` or similar.

**Context:** I'm trying to prepare a dict for a JSON API in Django, such that I have two models, `Evaluation` and its parent `Charity`.

In the view I filter for all Evaluations meeting certain parameters, and then use a dict comp nexted in a list comp on `evaluation.__dict__.items()` to drop Django's '_state' field (this isn't the focus of this question, but please tell me if you know a better practice!):

```
response = { 'evaluations': [{
    key:value for key, value in evaluation.__dict__.items()
    if key not in ['_state']} for evaluation in evaluations]}
```

But I want a good way to combine the fields `charity_name` and `charity_abbreviation` of each Evaluation's parent charity with the rest of that evaluation's fields. So far the best way I can find/think of is during the dict comp to conditionally check whether the field we're iterating through is `charity_id` and if so to look up that charity and return an array of the two fields.

But I haven't figured out how to do that, and it seems likely to end up with something very messy which isn't isn't functionally ideal, since I'd rather that array was two key:value pairs in line with the rest of the dictionary.

Comment: You seem to be reinventing the wheel, there are existing packages that help you serialize model data. See [Serializers from Django REST Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/) (There are ways to deal with related models in the serializer)

Comment: Share your models and your serializers ?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat , that answer was all I needed! Happy to mark it as correct if you want to post it as an official answer.